# how to merge data across data.frame rows based on identical column values

Tags: r, tidyverse

How would you merge values between rows that have identical values in `id_3`? I'm sure there's a better name for the question title but I'm struggling to find the appropriate operation/function name(s) for this procedure.

```
library(tidyverse)
id_1 <- c("x12", NA, "a_bc", NA)
id_2 <- c(NA, "gye", NA, "ab_c")
id_3 <- c("qwe", "ert", "abc", "abc")
param_1 <- c(0.21, 1.5, 0.23, NA)
param_12 <- c(0.05, 4.4, NA, 6.3)

df <- data.frame(id_1, id_2, id_3, param_1, param_12)
as_tibble(df)

#    id_1  id_2  id_3  param_1 param_12
#   <fct> <fct> <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 x12   NA    qwe      0.21     0.05
#  2 NA    gye   ert      1.5      4.4 
#  3 a_bc  NA    abc      0.23     NA   
#  4 NA    ab_c  abc      NA       6.3
```

desired `df`:

```
#    id_1  id_2  id_3  param_1 param_12
#   <fct> <fct> <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 x12   NA    qwe     0.21     0.05
#  2 NA    gye   ert     1.5      4.4 
#  3 a_bc  ab_c  abc     0.23     6.3
```

update - with additional column formats such as character:

```
id_1 <- c("x12", NA, "a_bc", NA)
id_2 <- c(NA, "gye", NA, "ab_c")
id_3 <- c("qwe", "ert", "abc", "abc")
param_1 <- c(0.21, 1.5, 0.23, NA)
param_12 <- c(0.05, 4.4, NA, 6.3)
desc_1 <- c("st", NA, "ko", NA)
desc_2 <- c(NA, "lo", NA, "vf")

df <- data.frame(id_1, id_2, id_3, param_1, param_12, desc_1, desc_2)
df <- df %>% mutate(desc_1 = as.character(desc_1), 
                    desc_2 = as.character(desc_2))

 # A tibble: 4 x 7
 #  id_1  id_2  id_3  param_1 param_12 desc_1 desc_2
 #  <fct> <fct> <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
 #1 x12   NA    qwe      0.21     0.05 st     NA    
 #2 NA    gye   ert      1.5      4.4  NA     lo    
 #3 a_bc  NA    abc      0.23    NA    ko     NA    
 #4 NA    ab_c  abc     NA        6.3  NA     vf 

df <- df %>% group_by(id_3) %>% 
      summarise_all(list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else .[!is.na(.)]

`Error: Column `desc_1` can't promote group 1 to character`
```

Comment: you need group_by() and summarise() from dplyr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'id_3' and `summarise` all the columns to return `NA` if all the values in that particular column is `NA` for a group or `else` remove the `NA` and return the first non-NA element

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(id_3) %>% 
   summarise_all(list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else .[!is.na(.)][1]))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  id_3  id_1  id_2  param_1 param_12
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 abc   a_bc  ab_c     0.23     6.3 
#2 ert   <NA>  gye      1.5      4.4 
#3 qwe   x12   <NA>     0.21     0.05
```

-Rstudio

[image]

#### Update

For the second dataset, after the columns were converted to `character` class, OP encountered error with `if(all(is.na(.))) NA`l.  If the columns are of same type, we can specify `NA_character`, `NA_real_`, `NA_integer_` to dispatch the correct NA for each type.  Here, we cannot do that, but there is one hacky option to return the 1st NA element in that column which will also have the correct type

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id_3) %>% 
   summarise_all(list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) .[!is.na(.)][1] 
           else .[!is.na(.)]))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  id_3  id_1  id_2  param_1 param_12 desc_1 desc_2
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
#1 abc   a_bc  ab_c     0.23     6.3  ko     vf    
#2 ert   <NA>  gye      1.5      4.4  <NA>   lo    
#3 qwe   x12   <NA>     0.21     0.05 st     <NA>
```

Comment: I think there may be a missing paranthesis (RStudio saying unexpected token/unmatched bracket), but I'm unable to edit myself.

Comment: @doconnor  I checked by copy/pasting the solution.  It is working for me though (in R console)

Comment: @doconnor  I am using `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘0.8.1’` on  `R 3.6.0`

Comment: it runs fine in RStudio but I get the red debug Xs - I'm using the same `dplyr` version but `R 3.5.1`. Once I can get admin permissions I'll update and retry.

Comment: @doconnor  It could be that issue.  I recently updated from 3.5.2 to 3.6 and there are some changes here and there

Comment: for the record - I updated to `3.6.0` and get the same thing - code runs but RStudio wants another paranthesis somehow.

Comment: @doconnor Let me check in Rstudio

Comment: @doconnor  You can see that it is working for me in rstudio version `Version 1.2.1522`

Comment: @doconnor  I think I downloaded the preview version to be in the bleeding edge

Comment: if it's an easy guess @akrun - if there were more columns with other formats, I can't see why your block wouldn't work? Trying on my non-example data.frame with additional character and date_time columns, I get `Error: Column 'my_column' can't promote group 1 to character`

Comment: @doconnor  Can you please update your post with an example so that I can test it

Comment: just updated above.  it works if I leave my descriptive columns like `desc_1` and `desc_2` as factors before running @akrun's block, so for my non example data.frame columns that are in character format to begin with, it seems I could `as.factor()` them and then run @akrun's block, unless there is a cleaner way.

Comment: @doconnor  I tried your example without converting to `character` and it is working fine.  Did you meant that you want to convert to `character` class

Comment: still having some trouble on my non-example data, I posted a follow up example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382379/how-to-merge-data-across-data-frame-rows-based-on-identical-column-values-with